# why symfony server doesnt run when i change env to prod instead of dev

Tags: symfony

im  having an issue with prod  env in symfony
server runs  fine  with dev env  but once i change it to   prod env  i cant run   the server anymore  and i  receive this error

```
There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace.

  You may be looking for a command provided by the "WebServerBundle" which is currently not installed. Try running "composer require symfony/web-server-bundle --dev".
```

using  atm symfony 4 & php 7.4

Comment: The bundle might be installed, but isn't active in the `prod` environment as [it's not meant to be used in public networks or production environments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). If you still want to test something, check `config/bundles.php`.

Comment: i checked that file and tried to change  all lines   that contains dev to false instead of true but that didnt help so what  should i do   in case  i want   to move to projet to production ?

Comment: You can add `'prod' => true` or `'all' => true`, as explained in [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/bundles.html), by changing `'dev'` to `false` you are disabling the bundle. However, as I said earlier, the webserver bundle is not designed to run a production site, it might be ok if you just want to do a quick check, but otherwise you should [install a real webserver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of standard

`symfony serve`

you need to use

`symfony server:prod`

```
% symfony help server:prod

Description:
  Switch a project to use Symfony's production environment

Usage:
  symfony local:server:prod [options]

Options:
  --dir=value  Project directory
  --off        Disable prod mode
```

Comment: I think he's using the [webserver bundle](https://github.com/symfony/web-server-bundle), not the symfony local server.

Comment: yes im using webserver bundle